# Why are natural splines almost always cubic?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, splines

By natural spline, I mean a regression spline that's linear at the boundary (i.e. the regions where X is smaller than the smallest knot or larger than the largest knot).

I know that for smoothing splines, the function that minimizes the relevant objective function is a shrunken version of a natural cubic spline with knots at each of the observations.

But for a natural spline estimated by least squares (or perhaps lasso/ridge regression) with a smaller number of knots... should the spline *necessarily* be cubic? Or (if the goal is prediction of a target variable in a machine learning context), should the degree be chosen by cross-validation instead of always using cubic?

Comment: Great question! (+1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably anticlimactic... I think this is a bit of conversion if we want to consider the resulting fit to be smooth. It stems as well as feeds on the fact that by *smooth* function one commonly refers to "*twice differentiable*". To quote Faraway's [*Linear Models with R*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Linear-Models-Chapman-Statistical-Science/dp/1439887330): "*The basis function is continuous and is also continuous in its first and second derivatives at each knotpoint. This property ensures the smoothness of the fit.*".

To start with an example: Such a convention immediately takes care of Taylor's theorem such that if $g$ is a smooth function there exist a $\psi \in (0,x)$ such that $g(x) = g(0) + xg'(0) + \frac{x^2}{2}g''(\psi)$. Higher order differentials definitely do matter at times but the usual convention is to check the first two and proceed.

Additionally, following the rationale from Ramsay & Silverman's seminal book on [*Functional Data Analysis*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Functional-Data-Analysis-Springer-Statistics/dp/038740080X), the second  derivative $g''(x)$ of a function at $x$ is often called its curvature at $x$ and the squared integral of it (i.e. the integrated squared second derivative: $\int [g''(x)]^2dx$) can be seen as a natural measure of a function smoothness (or roughness depend how we look at this). This working assumption of "smooth enough because second derivative exists" is almost universal when working with curves/functional data (e.g. Horváth & Kokoszka's [*Inference for Functional Data with Applications*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Inference-Functional-Applications-Springer-Statistics/dp/1461436540) and Ferraty & Vieu's [*Nonparametric Functional Data Analysis*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nonparametric-Functional-Data-Analysis-Statistics/dp/0387303693/) put similar convention in place); once again this *working assumption* and *not* a hard requirement. It also goes without saying that if we work with $g''(x)$ as our unit of analysis we assume that $g''''(x)$ exist and so forth. As a side-note: the existence of a second derivative is associated with the isotropy of a function (e.g. see Switzer (1976) [*Geometrical measures of the smoothness of random functions*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3212668)) which is a reasonable assumption for data assumed to lie on a continuum (e.g. have spatial dependence).

Let me note that there is no reason why a higher or lower order requirement for the continuity of derivatives cannot be used. For example, we might choose to use a piecewise linear interpolant in cases where we have an insufficient amount of data. Finally, the degree of smoothness is indeed chosen using a cross-validation approach (usually Generalised Cross-Validation to be more exact) based on the metric we choose (see for example the popular function [`mgcv::gam`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/gam.html) does exactly that when fitting the smooth splines, Yao et al. (2005) [*Functional linear regression analysis for longitudinal data*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1140191677) does the same when picking the bandwidth of the kernel smoothers, etc.)

One might find the following Math.SE thread on: [Is second derivative of a function related to curve smoothness?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735824/is-second-derivative-of-a-function-related-to-curve-smoothness) also insightful, unfortunately it does not contain a definite answer.

So, "*why are the natural splines almost always cubic?*" Because assuming the existence of second derivatives and thus the need for a cubic fit, is a good convention for most cases. ☺